# com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.FileNameException

Tags: file-upload, file-io, liferay-6

I get this exception when I try to upload a file to a folder in Liferay Document and Media.

com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.FileNameException
    at com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.service.impl.DLFileEntryLocalServiceImpl.addFileEntry(DLFileEntryLocalServiceImpl.java:123)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)

Answer (score 0):

This would happen when your file name fails for method

`protected boolean isValidName(String name) {
        if ((name == null) ||
            (name.contains("\\\\")) ||
            (name.contains("//")) ||
            (name.contains(":")) ||
            (name.contains("*")) ||
            (name.contains("?")) ||
            (name.contains("\"")) ||
            (name.contains("<")) ||
            (name.contains(">")) ||
            (name.contains("|")) ||
            (name.contains("[")) ||
            (name.contains("]")) ||
            (name.contains("'")) ||
            (name.contains("..\\")) ||
            (name.contains("../")) ||
            (name.contains("\\..")) ||
            (name.contains("/.."))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }`

HTH,